# Apache Cassandra INSERT-only permissions

Tags: permissions, cassandra

Looking at the [Cassandra documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/security.html#data-control), it appears that the smallest write-only permission on a table you can grant is MODIFY, which includes UPDATE, DELETE and TRUNCATE.

Is there a proper way to restrict this further to ONLY grant INSERT and no other permission, ideally for the user/role itself, without requiring further logic application side?

I would like for ONLY the DBA to have the ability to alter data in a table, the application user should have INSERT-only rights.

If it's not possible using the permission model only, could [triggers](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/triggers.html) be the answer and are there known drawbacks for this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way right now because it's how the Cassandra works.

`INSERTS` in Cassandra are really upserts, so if you insert data with the same primary key, then they are modified, like you do with `UPDATE`.  And similarly, if you insert `null` values, then you're deleting the data.